# Erro : Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

Pessoal estou precisando criar um App, ainda sou novo em android, e estou com o seguinte erro, e não estou encontrando a solução. Pesquisei inclusive aqui no fórum. Alguem sabe o que pode ser?
Erro:

> 10-07 17:10:53.950 10339-10339/com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication, PID: 10339
>                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication/com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
>                                                                                               Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication.MainActivity
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
>                                                                                                       ... 13 more
>                                                                                               Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication.MainActivity
>                                                                                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                                       ... 12 more
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tela_inicial);

    Button bttCheguei = (Button) findViewById(R.id.credenciar);
    Button bttQrcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttqrcode);
    bttQrcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LeitorQRCode.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
    bttCheguei.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewProjeto.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
    Button bttConhecerProjetos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.projetos);
    bttConhecerProjetos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Projeto.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });

}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cristianhaas.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="barcode" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SegundaTela"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.emanuel.teste.AJUDA" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewProjeto"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".ViewProjeto" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Projeto"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".Projeto" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LeitorQRCode"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".LeitorQRCode" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BarcodeCaptureActivity"
        android:label="Read Barcode" />

</application>
```

Agradeço desde já, qualquer ajuda!!

Comment: Aqui compilou e rodou sem nenhum problema. O que exatamente causa o erro?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida, ela nem abre a tela Inicial. E exibe a mensagem que parou de funcionar

Comment: Ok, então isole melhor o erro porque o problema não tá nesse código que você me passou. Crie um novo projeto só com ele e veja você mesmo.

Comment: @PabloAlmeisa, obrigado pela ajuda, fiz o que você disse, fui peneirando para achar onde estava o erro, pois achei que pelo log do erro era ali na main. Com isso chego a conclusão que PHP > Java haha Obrigado